# Python os.read blocks until newline character

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I have an XBee plugged into a Raspberry PI. Here is the Python 3.4 code I am using:

```
f = os.open("/dev/ttyUSB0", os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK)

print("Writing...")
b = bytes("hello","utf-8")
os.write(f,b)

print("Press return to start read")
cmd = input()

print("Reading...")
ret = os.read(f,10)
if ret == None:
        print("ret = None")
else:
        print("ret = {}".format(ret))

 os.close(f)
```

Yesterday, this all worked as I expected.  The read command returned immediately, with zero bytes if there wasn't anything to read.

Today I added code to another part of the project that writes to a text file and includes a thread RLock.  Now the above code does something different.  If there are no bytes waiting to be read, or there are bytes waiting to be read but they don't end with an 0x0D, I get an error:

```
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

But is there are bytes waiting to be read that end with an 0x0D, the read function returns those bytes including the 0x0D.

Update: I have reformated the system, and the fault has not gone away, which suggests it wasn't the addition of the file and thread locking code that caused the problem.

I ran minicom and the problem has gone away, so maybe I should be doing something with serial configuration on the device before I open it as a file?

This is the line that returns the os.read to its original behaviour:

minicom -b 9600 -o -D /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: Can you include the code that adds the lock? The newline thing makes it sound like somehow the read is being buffered (I know using a normal file-like object as an iterator will block waiting for the newline or EOF), but afaik `os.open` returns an unbuffered file handle

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have update my question with the locking code.

Comment: Are you closing the handle for the serial port, but still reading from it?  If so, then it's possible that the underlying file handle for your trace.txt file is the same as what it was for the USB port.  Unix operating systems assign file handles in incrementing order and will re-use handles.  Try this and see for yourself: https://gist.github.com/jszakmeister/e18607a026749956f0bd7a30cd148fa6

Comment: For the record, I'd consider returning empty `bytes` when no data is available to be an error. `os.read` should only return empty `bytes` when it's reached end of file. When it's not at end of file, but there is no data available to read on a non-blocking file descriptor, it should raise [`BlockingIOError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BlockingIOError); that's what that error is for.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `BlockingIOError` only ever gets raised by `io.write()`. `io.read()` returns `None` and `os.read()` returns an empty byte object.

Comment: @dhke: Nope. `os.read` is poorly documented (it doesn't mention how it interacts with `O_NONBLOCK`), but it absolutely can raise an exception. [`os.read`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Modules/posixmodule.c#l8043) is implemented in terms of [`_Py_read`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/fileutils.c#l1166). The latter is basically just wrapping [`read`(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read), and when `read` returns `-1`, Python raises an exception based on `errno`. `read` for non-blocking fds will return `-1` and set `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` when there is no available data.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Hmm. My bad, I tested with /dev/null, which of course just EOFs straight. Still, `io.read()` clearly behaves differently, which is ... at the very least a little annyoing. Side note: `EWOULDBLOCK` is [not allowed by SingleUnix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/read.html).

Comment: @dhke: And on checking, while the `io` module docs state that `RawIOBase`'s `read`-like methods return `None` for non-blocking streams without available data, and [`FileIO.readinto`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Modules/_io/fileio.c#l637) will clear the error in this case (even though it's implemented in terms of `_Py_read`), you're often using file-like objects through `BufferedIOBase`, which explicitly documents that it _does_ raise for non-blocking w/o data: "A BlockingIOError is raised if the underlying raw stream is in non blocking-mode, and has no data available at the moment."

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the two different behaviours are related to the CTS/RTS flow control settings on the serial port. Try turning CTS/RTS on or off to get the behaviour you want.